# Download a file from server (C++ target)

Tags: c++, http, haxe

I'm new to Haxe and for my first project I want to write a simple program that will download a file from the server. I'm targeting C++.

I've been looking at **[`haxe.Http`](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/Http.html)**, but I don't think it's suitable for binary data, it has an `onData` and a `responseData` property, but these are both strings. I also don't think it would be suitable for large files, just because it stores all response data in memory.

- Is there another class I should be using instead of `haxe.Http`?
- Should I write my own HTTP parser using [`sys.net.Socket`](http://api.haxe.org/sys/net/Socket.html)?

Comment: Anybody care to comment regarding the downvotes? Perhaps I can fix the question if you explain the problem.

Comment: Probably because you're on your way to an off-topic trifecta. Your first two questions appear to be too broad and the last one is not within the scope of SO (asking for tutorials).

Comment: Keep in mind that not all string classes (i.e. std::string) include a size or length member and having a null character in the middle of the string is perfectly acceptable. Receiving binary data in a string object can be quite acceptable in these cases.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious OK, but what about large files. It looks like all data is held in memory and passed to the `onData` method in one go. I would prefer to handle the data in chunks for large files, or maybe pipe directly to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner in Haxe, as a simple start I would simply try to use the synchronous (blocking) way, as it's very simple, then writing to content to a file to check whether it really works in C++.

For instance:

```
class TestHttp {
    public static function main() { 
        var content : String = haxe.Http.requestUrl("http://somedomain/path/to/file");
        sys.io.File.write("/path/to/some/local/file", true).writeString(content);
        trace(content.length + " bytes downloaded");
    }
}
```

If this works for you in C++, then you can spend more time writing an asynchronous solution, using onData or even Sockets. I don't write an asynchronous solution for now, as it would require your program to have an infinite loop (while(true)) and I'm not too sure if you already have a main loop at this point.

Comment: Also don't forget to close FileOutput returned by File.write().